# Rails 3.1 and Paperclip unexplained route problem in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Please help, I don't know what to try anymore....

On my machine everything works fine. But on production box when hitting submit, something is cutting route.

Command path for paperclip in environment is set properly.

**This is what I get in production.log when submitting upload form:**

```
 Started POST "/app_medias/1/media_image"
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/1/media_image"):
```

**/app_medias/ gone from the route wtf???**

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => "http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

**route:**

```
  resources :app_medias do 
    member do
      post 'media_image' #upload action
    end
  end
```

**rake routes:**

```
media_image_app_media POST |  /app_medias/:id/media_image(.:format)  |  {:controller=>"app_medias", :action=>"media_image"}
```

**controller:**

```
  def show
    @media = AppMedia.find(params[:id])
    @media_image = @media.media_images.build
  end

  def media_image
    @media = AppMedia.find(params[:id])
    @media_image = @media.media_images.build(params[:media_image])
    if @media_image.save
      flash[:notice] = "Saved"
      redirect_to app_media_path(@media)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error"
      render :action => 'show'
    end
  end
```

**model**

```
  has_attached_file :media_image,
                    :styles => {
                          :thumb => "50x50#",
                          :small  => "x110",
                          :original => "x600" } , 
                          :url => ("/assets/_media/:attachment/:id_:style_:basename.:extension").downcase,
                          :path => (":rails_root/public/assets/_media/:attachment/:id_:style_:basename.:extension").downcase
```

**view:**

```
<%= form_for :media_image, :as => @media_image, :url => {:action => "media_image"}, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :media_image %><%= f.submit 'Upload', :disable_with => 'uploading...', :class => 'button primary' %>
<%- end -%>
```

I tried also form_for @media_image, :url => {:action => "media_image} ... localy works, not in production.

Can somebody help? I'm stuck...

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `:url => media_image_app_media_path` in your form instead of setting the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! **ModSecurity** is the problem. Now is off, and upload is working fine.